# BeautifulSoup with Recursion: Get html tags with the most children / longest path in HTML

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get HTML tag that has the most children.

Example HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta></meta>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <span> Longest Path </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""
```

What I would like to get is `html > body > div > p > span`

Now I'm trying to get all paths using recursion and bs4

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML = """
<html>
    <head>
        <meta></meta>
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <span> Longest Path </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""


def longest_path():
    """ Function that will return the longest path in the HTML """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "html.parser")
    tags = soup.find_all(recursive=False)
    paths = []
    for tag in tags:
        path = []
        full_path = _recursive_path(tag, path)
        paths.append(full_path)
    return paths


def _recursive_path(tag, path):
    """ Function that uses recursion to calculate path """
    path.append(tag.name)
    tag_children = tag.find_all(recursive=False)
    if not tag_children:
        return path

    for tag_child in tag_children:
        _recursive_path(tag_child, path)


print(longest_path())
```

But this so far doesn't produce  results I want. Any ideas?

Comment: It's pretty simple to do this (or something along these lines) using lxml, if available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator. The HTML can be traversed by iterating over `soup.contents` and incrementing a counter at each level:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup, NavigableString as ns
def get_paths(d, p = [], c = 0):
   if not (k:=[i for i in getattr(d, 'contents', []) if not isinstance(i, ns)]):
      yield (c, ' > '.join(p+[d.name]))
   else:
      for i in k:
         yield from get_paths(i, p=p+[d.name],c = c+1)

_, path = max(get_paths(soup(HTML, 'html.parser').html), key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Output:

```
'html > body > div > p > span'
```